# Ruby and Diophantine equations--hash issues

Tags: ruby, hash, diophantine

I'm new to programming and ruby.  I'm working on code that deals with a specific Diophantine  equation (from an MIT opencourseware problem), and just kind of seeing what I can do with it.

The code produces three arrays and a hash of two of them for a particular linear equation with three variables.

Here's the code:

```
def diophantine_solutions(x)
  #For all x > 1, finds values for a, b, c such that 6a + 9b + 20c = x,
  #Creates array of solvable x, unsolvable x, 
  #Creates hash of solvable x with possible values of a, b, c

  nopes=(1..x).to_a #will contain sums with no solutions at the end
  yups=[] #has solvalbes
  yups_values=[] #solutions for a, b, c
  yups_hash={} #sums with the solutions

  while x>0
    for a in (0..x/6):
      for b in (0..x/9):
        for c in (0..x/20):
          total=6*a + 9*b + 20*c
          if total==x
            yups<< x
            yups_values<< [a, b, c]
          end          
        end
      end
    end
    x=x-1
  end

  yups_hash=[yups.zip(yups_values)]
  yups=yups.uniq
  nopes=nopes-yups
  puts yups_hash[20]
end

diophantine_solutions(20)
```

What I'm trying to do now is access the individual hash pairings to make sure they are lining up right, but

```
puts yups_hash[]
```

returns nil for any number.  Any help?  Also, being new as I am, if there are better ways to do anything I've done, I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be:

```
yups_hash = Hash[yups.zip(yups_values)]
```

With the caveat that I don't know what's *supposed* be happening, but the `yups_hash` name implies it should be a hash, not an array with a bunch of arrays in it.

Once there's an actual hash the output for 20 is:

```
0 0 1
```

This matches the definition, at least.

Comment: This returns the error: `[]': odd number of arguments for Hash (ArgumentError).  I'm trying to make a hash out of it, pairing a value of x with [a,b,c] for each value of x that has a solution, and for each set of [a,b,c] such that they together satisfy the equation for x.  I want to collect that information and call which variations of [a,b,c] solve the equation for the same value of x.

Comment: @quiet_engine What version of Ruby? Works fine for me.